# My Raspberry Pi 3's wifi and ethernet capabilities stopped working, but the Pi can still connect to Bluetooth devices. How can I fix this?

Tags: pi-3, networking, wifi

I really do not know much about Raspberry Pis and what information is important, so if you guys need anything, I can give it to you.

Comment: is there anything important on the pi? files or a certain configuration you wish to save? because my recommendation is to simply wipe it clean and start over.

Comment: What are the various little colored lights doing? Did you change anything (connections, hardware, software, updates?)? Did you try a fresh image?